# How to use np.insert in iterations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to insert an array to some specific positions of another  array.
For example, say that you have

```
import numpy as np

pos = np.array([1, 3, 4])
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
vals = np.array([-1,-1])
```

I want that `vals` is inserted to `arr` in the positions specified by `pos` so that at the end I have `result = [0,-1,-1,1,2, -1,-1, 3,-1,-1,4,5]`.

That is, `[result[i], result[i+1]]` should be equal to `val` for all `i` in `pos`.

I tried the following loop:

```
for ii in pos:
    arr = np.insert(arr, ii, vals)
```

but it does not work because the size of `arr` is increasing at every iteration.

Comment: Please double check the expected output

Comment: I updated it, thanks for highlighting it.

Comment: Why do this iteratively?  Why not just one `insert`, with multiple positions?

Comment: @hpaulj `np.insert` cannot insert more than one value when multiple insertion points are provided (that would work if `vals` only had one item)

Comment: @mozway, I have a vague memory from previous SO that there was a way to do multiple inserts.  But now the best I can do is use `repeat/tile` to replicate `pos/vals` to the same size, `np.insert(arr, pos.repeat(2),np.tile(vals,3))`

Comment: Repeated `insert` is inefficient, because as you note it increases `arr` length each time - a whole new array.  Same as for repeated `concatentate/ append/ etc`.  `insert` is python code, though a bit messy because it can handle axis.  But the concept is simple.  Make a 'result' array, and fill it with the `arr` values and the `vals` values in the relevant slots.  It takes into account that `pos` values need increments.

Answer (score 1):

Since `vals` is fixed, you could account for the change in size:

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

for ii in pos + np.arange(len(pos))*len(vals):
    arr = np.insert(arr, ii, vals)
```

Or:

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

for n, ii in enumerate(pos):
    arr = np.insert(arr, ii+n*len(vals), vals)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0, -1, -1,  1,  2, -1, -1,  3, -1, -1,  4,  5])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [130]: pos = np.array([1, 3, 4])
     ...: arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
     ...: vals = np.array([-10,10]) # more interesting
```

Expanding the `pos` and `vals` to matching lengths:

```
In [131]: pos.repeat(2)
Out[131]: array([1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4])    
In [133]: np.tile(vals, 3)
Out[133]: array([-10,  10, -10,  10, -10,  10])

In [134]: np.insert(arr, pos.repeat(2), np.tile(vals, 3))
Out[134]: array([  0, -10,  10,   1,   2, -10,  10,   3, -10,  10,   4,   5])
```

`insert` creates a new array each time it's called, with all the attendant copies from both `arr` and `vals`.  With repeated calls you have to take into account the growth of `arr`.

Note that `insert` takes such a growth into account. If I take the expanded `pos` and add [0,1,2...], I can index the insertions in the result:

```
In [135]: Out[134][Out[131]+np.arange(6)]
Out[135]: array([-10,  10, -10,  10, -10,  10])
```

Similarly I could make a `result=np.zeros(12)`, figure out where the `arr` elements belong, and assign the `vals` elements to the remaining slots.  The indexing math takes some care, but isn't fancy or time consuming.  `insert` is primarily a convenience function, not an exotic compiled one.

One approach is to make a boolean mask of where we want to insert values:

```
In [151]: mask = np.zeros(12,bool)    
In [152]: mask[pos.repeat(2)+np.arange(6)]=True    
In [153]: mask
Out[153]: 
array([False,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True,
        True, False, False])
```

Make a target array:

```
In [154]: result = np.zeros(12, int)
```

Assign the original and new values:

```
In [155]: result[~mask] = arr    
In [156]: result[mask] = np.tile(vals,3)

In [157]: result
Out[157]: array([  0, -10,  10,   1,   2, -10,  10,   3, -10,  10,   4,   5])
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of `tile` and `repeat`. Thanks! A couple of suggestion to make your answer more clear: 1) Could you remove the IPython prompts in the cose snippets? 2) Could you replace the hard-coded values with what they actually are (for example, `pos.repeat(2)` with `pos.repeat(len(vals))`?